# jquery .click function not working, way to see in chrome dev tools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following script attached to a button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('.addToCartButton').click(function() {
                fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
                    content_ids: ['<?php echo  (int)$product_info['products_id']; ?>'],
                    content_type: 'product'
                });
            });


        </script>
```

I am trying to activate the facebook addtocart on button click.

The button code is:

```
<button id="tdb1" type="submit" class="addToCartButton" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
   <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-cart"></span>
   <span class="ui-button-text">Add to Cart</span>
</button>
```

Is there a way to check if it is firing in chrome dev tools?
Am I missing something?

Comment: do you attach the event listener after the DOM is ready? if you do it before you should use the.on() method insted

Answer (score 0):

Add a `debugger` statement before and after the `click` function and make sure that the developer console is open.

The console will break at the `debugger` statement and you can debug from there.

Comment: So I tried this, and it does in fact pause after clicking the button. So I guess that means the class is being detected and the click is working. So I am not sure what to do with that because it seems like the FB script is then not firing?

Comment: What does ‘console.log’ of the element produce?